# how to get the custom page event happened data to observer in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module, event-observer, custom-quote

I have custom module observer in Magento 2

```
<event name="controller_action_postdispatch_mpquotesystem_sellerquote_quoteedit">
        <observer name="webkul_mpquote_sellerquote_managequote_after_observer2" instance="Webkul\Mpquotesystem\Observer\Sellerquoteupdateafter" />
    </event>
```

after the event happened I want the 
details of the page - data

> controller_action_postdispatch_mpquotesystem_sellerquote_quoteedit

how I can do this

**Like this --- if I create order observer - getting an order in the observer**

Comment: Not sure exactly what is needed. At what time this event fires and what information you need after its executed ? not able to get page-data

Comment: i have created for observer after **quote_edit** page fired

Comment: after **quote_edit** page fired i have getting customer id

Comment: i want to get which quote  is edited in that **quote_edit**

to my observer